# Stereo to Mono Sound

Tags: audio, samsung-galaxy-s-4

Is there a way to digitally convert stereo sound tracks to mono ones, while playing?
I need this feature because sometime I split my headset with other people, and hearing only one channel is quite awful. 
I do not want to change my music player, which is n7player (paid).
My phone is Galaxy S4 with Cyanogenmod 11 (Kitkat 4.4.2).

The only answers I was able to find were to use PowerAmp player, but again, I don't want to switch to it.

Comment: If you don't want to switch your music player, that probably only leaves mixers/equalizers. The Android system IMHO doesn't come equipped with such a feature.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought, but I was not able to find such app (paid or not)

Comment: Neither was I, sorry, or I had mentioned it. Checked for about half an hour, but no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Android 4.4:

1. From your homescreen, hit the <kbd>Menu</kbd> key and open *System Settings*
2. Go to *Accessibility*, tap cancel on "need a screen reader" to bypass / scroll down to "Mono Audio"
3. Uncheck box

Done!

Answer (score 3):

In S4, go to `Settings > My device > Accessibility > Hearing`. You will find the Mono audio option there.

EDIT: You can download Boeffla Sound Control from play store. This app is able to convert Stereo sound to Mono. For this you must first install Busybox which is also available on play store. Your devices needs to be rooted. Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: This option is available only in the stock ROM, and I'm using Cyanogenmod.

Comment: This feature seems to be not available on CM. You can post your request [here](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/blog/developer-relations)

Comment: As of 2018, this answer (first part) is correct (even if maybe at the time it was posted, it was not) for latest CM/LOS.